# How to enable CONFIG_PREEMPT option in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am a new bee in Linux kernel programming, trying to work with an old kernel Linux 2.6.32 on x86_64. I want to enable the CONFIG_PREEMPT option in it but can not find information about how can I do it. I can compile a new kernel with my preferred options, but do not know what I need to do in this case. So can anyone please tell me

How can I enable CONFIG_PREEMPT option? Do I need to recompile the kernel again with new menuconfig? In that case which option is responsible for CONFIG_PREEMPT?

I think it's trivial for anyone who worked with this before, so please give me your valuable help!

Answer (score 2):

CONFIG_PREEMPT in a main part of the kernel, you can not modularize it. So if you don't have already a PREEMPT kernel, you need to compile it from sources. The option is selected by its name 'PREEMPT' or edit file manually to activate it.

While in menuconfig, press the `/` key, and search for `PREEMPT`.  This will show you where the option is and what it will be called in the menu.

Check if it is not available in your preferred distribution.